# Is the sentence “As though Bill Donohue didn’t have enough to be cranky about” self-complete?

Tags: sentence, sentence-starts

I’m a regular reader of New York Times columnist, Maureen Dowd’s column, which provides me with lot of input of contemporary English expressions that I cannot learn from ordinary English text books and readings.

Today’s (February 14) New York Times carries her article titled “That Old Black Magic” starting with the following statement:

> As though Bill Donohue didn’t have enough to be cranky about.
>
> The perpetually apoplectic Catholic League president is on the rampage about President Obama trying to make sure women working at Catholic institutions get insurance coverage for birth control.
>
> What’s wrong with the rhythm method anyway? That’s how I got here.

I wonder if the first line and the second copy block is a single sentence connected with the conjunction, “As though.”

Why did she put a period after “be cranky about” and separated it from the following line, “The perpetually apoplectic Catholic League president is on the rampage ...” with a space.

Are they separate sentences? If so, what is the function of “As though”? Is this Dowd’s special writing style?

Comment: By most reckonings, *"As though/if X"* isn't a "sentence" - it's a clause which in this case would normally be followed by *something else **also** causing Donohue to be cranky*. But there's no law saying every sentence must be complete and "self-contained". If there were, oP's final sentence would be invalid, since it doesn't tell us what "this" refers to.

Comment: That is journalese for you, not necessarily formal grammar. It makes a stronger "statement" than a grammatically correct and complete sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea was to make the reader pause and think about all the things Bill Donohue has to be cranky about. She wanted her reader in a very particular frame of mind as they go into that next paragraph.

Comment: I agree.  This is an example of good writing that isn't grammatically correct; it is done on purpose and is effective.  You get a perfect picture of the person speaking.  The whole section made me laugh!